# Disable 'use strict' in Google Maps Drawing Library (for compatibility with asp.net __doPostBack)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to turn off 'use strict' within the Google maps drawing library (accessed through http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&sensor=false).

This has never been an issue for me before but as I'm sure some of you are aware, JavaScript's strict mode is incompatible with asp.net's __doPostBack method and throws an error in Firefox and Chrome( Illegal access to a strict mode caller function, or access censored in ff).

Alas both the drawing library and the ability to __doPostBack are imperative to the application I am working on, so I cannot simply remove one or the other.

As far as I am aware it is not possible to simply download the library independently of the full maps api and comment out the offending line. If I am wrong on this I will be overjoyed.

I wasn't sure whether or not to tag this as JavaScript so If I was in the wrong there apologies.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download [the library](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&sensor=false), save it as `.js`, and comment out (or remove) the `"use strict"` line.

Comment: In which case I apologise for being dense, I presumed that the library was generated dynamically as a result of the 'libraries=drawing' call and that it was not available on it's own. 

Amazingly glad to hear that I'm wrong and thanks for the lightning fast response.

Comment: Actually on further inspection the api itself merely loads a number of other libraries (including the drawing library).

I'll merely have to modify the original script to load my modified version of the drawing library, thought I'd post this in-case anyone else has the same issue. 

Thanks again.