# "arguments.callee" throwing exception in ES5

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, ecmascript-5

#### The issue

> [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them]

Founded on *`f.Application`*`> __proto__ > *` from Marionette.JS' object (`Backbone.Marionette.Application();`):

[image: Issue]

#### Knowledge

ES5 *prohibited* the use of `arguments.callee` according [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee). However, I am using some third-party library that probably use it and I don't know how to deal with.

My environment is:

- jQuery
- Require.JS
- Underscore.JS
- Backbone.JS
- Marionette.JS
- Handlebars

#### General

I removed `'use strict';` from all my own `js` files – not third-party libraries; my own scripts coded from scratch – and I can't see what's going wrong here – I need to be enlightened.

So, can someone suggest me something? And yes, I saw similar threads *web-around*, but no success at all – I think my issue is more specific than others.

#### The past

For those who ask, I wasn't working with Marionette.JS before in this application – just Backbone.JS. The error began to happen when I migrated my application from "native" Backbone to Marionette.

Comment: Found a similar, though seemingly outdated bug here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/387. Could you perhaps mention in the question the browsers you test in as well, as not all support strict mode? And the problem comes from Marionnette then, right? Personally, I've been reading you should avoid strict mode unless you thoroughly tested & retested it in different environments. Perhaps file an issue at the Github page?

Comment: I wouldn't say "prohibited", more that strict mode prevents access to them. I expect you can remove `'use strict'` everywhere, there shouldn't be anything that works in strict mode that fails in non–strict mode (given that the code likely runs in browsers that don't implement strict mode, such as IE 9).

Comment: @RobG Do you mean remove `'use strict';` even from all third-party libraries?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge—yes. [*Strict mode*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C) just makes some parts of the language stricter (no access to *callee*, *caller*, *eval*, *with*, etc.) but doesn't add any features. A lot of browsers in use don't use strict mode, so any general library it must be written to work at least in non–strict mode.

Comment: A case where strict mode matters is `if (tyepof this == 'undefined')` which will always be false in non–strict mode, but might be true in strict mode. But I can't see that anyone would do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable 'use strict' in Google Maps Drawing Library (for compatibility with asp.net \_\_doPostBack)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742051/disable-use-strict-in-google-maps-drawing-library-for-compatibility-with-asp)

Comment: @RobG with regards to what you wrote "there shouldn't be anything that works in strict mode that fails in non–strict mode", are you sure this is the case? Also, are you sure that this is STILL the case? I am asking because of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655625/is-it-safe-to-remove-use-strict-from-a-third-party-library

Answer (score 0):

In the Marionette source:

- [application.js](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/application.js)
- [module.js](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/module.js)

there is no 'use strict' on the functions themselves, but there is 'use strict' on the Marionette core:

- [backbone.marionette.js](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js)

Compare the downloaded source to the project source, and verify that your `addInitializer` method is within a scope that does not include the 'use strict' pragma.

**References**

- [Annotated Marionette Source](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette)
- [Annoted Source: backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html)
- [ECMA-262, 5th Edition: A survey of the latest JavaScript specification - Strict mode in practice](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ecma262/#sm_practice)
- [Marionette.js Issue #387: Marionette not compatible with strict mode](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/387)