# Is it safe to remove "use strict" from a third party library

Tags: javascript, browser, strict-mode

I am using a pretty terrible library on the front-end. In their installation instructions, they tell to copy-paste some code, that starts with "use strict". And yet their code throws an error in some old browsers.

I am tempted to simply remove the "use strict" instruction from the code I have copy-pasted.

Is it safe though? Can it lead to a change of behaviour for the end user, apart from being more flexible?

The MDN article about strict mode states that `Strict mode isn't just a subset: it intentionally has different semantics from normal code`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode.

Comment: Removing strict-mode can lead to errors, yes. That doesn't mean it will, just that code that will throw on removing `"use strict;"` is possible. If you ask me, programming javascript in non-strict in 2022 is very, very questionable.

Comment: `use strict` is **not** about flexibility. JS by initial design is a very forgiving language. It will make some assumptions instead of throwing errors when you use illegal syntax.  Obviously it's possible that side effects of such *automation* could produce undesirable outcomes.

Comment: strict-mode is a soft-deprecation of legacy features and behavior from the beginning of the web - esm was the next step, moving to strict-mode by default. If you want to have sleepless nights, because you've landed in the web-compat annex, good luck. PS: afaik even browsers from the stone age (IE11, not IE8, see https://caniuse.com/use-strict) support strict mode somewhat, but even for IE8, it was designed so it would be just an inert statement, in engines that don't support it.